# jQuery filter issue on IE8 and IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I am having an issue where a simple filter script is not firing in IE7 or IE8.  I at least want it to work on IE8. IE7 is awash for me.  The site is a test for right now. But I can not seem to get the filter working. It works fine on IE9 and Chrome and Firefox of course but not on IE8. I am using jQuery 1.8.1. Below is the JS and here is the URL: 
http://carlosmosqueda.com/tastytacos/menu.html - The filter is at the top of the page for the menu items.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
 //Menu filter


 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('#menuFilter li').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("activeFilter");
        $(this).toggleClass("activeFilter");
        filter();
     });

     var filter = function() {
     var classes = $("#menuFilter li.activeFilter")
    .map(function() {
       return $(this).data("filter");
     })
    .toArray();

    $(".item").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var show = classes.every(function(aClass) {
        return $this.hasClass(aClass);
    });

    if(show) {
        $this.fadeIn(200);
    } else {
       $this.fadeOut(200);
    }
   });
 };
```

Comment: How is it not working? Most people won't have IE8 and won't be able to replicate your issue, so it would help to have a description and some error messages (if there are any).

Comment: We have a decent amount of our customer that, very sadly, still use IE8 because they are still using Window XP, ugh.  BUT I saw in the Error pane in IE there is a method called .every(). This is code I utilized from another site. This is probably the culprit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) isn't supported by IE8 and below, so this line won't work:

```
var show = classes.every(function(aClass) {
```

Either use a polyfill (on the MDN page) or use a `for` loop.

With a `for` loop, you could do:

```
var has_all = true;

for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
    if (!$this.hasClass(classes[i])) {
        has_all = false;
        break;
    }
}

if (has_all) {
    $this.fadeIn();
} else {
    $this.fadeOut();
}
```

Comment: Yeh I saw the .every error.  So a for loop will work. What about the .each() for jQuery? It is basically the same thing right?

Comment: @ClosDesign: `Array.every` returns `true` or `false`. `.each()` just calls the callback on each element (like a `for` loop).

Comment: I really hate to ask, but do you have happen to know how I would change the above code for that variable to use a polyfill or for loop?  I know the jQuery stuff pretty well, but of course like most people who started with jQuery my straight Javascript skills are not great.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Thank you very much man. I REALLY appreciate it.  Still learning so this is very helpful.